# Is there any 'is_member'-like method for List class?

Tags: python, list

I would like to use a function to filter out items of list not in another list.

If possible I would like to avoid using lambda function.

But I have not been able to spot any 'is_member' method for List class. Is there one?

Here is the type of code I am looking for.

```py
to_filter=['age','height','name', 'address']
as_float=['age', 'height', 'weight']

are_float=filter(as_float.is_member, to_filter)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Simple list comprehension would do `[i for i in to_filter if i not in as_float]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `__contains__` method, which is what the `in` operator uses:

```py
In [1]: to_filter=['age','height','name', 'address'] 
   ...: as_float=['age', 'height', 'weight']                                                                                                                  

In [2]: list(filter(to_filter.__contains__, as_float))                                                                                                        
Out[2]: ['age', 'height']
```

Comment: Did you switch them intentionally?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure which direction the OP wanted, but they should be able to figure that out themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
are_float = [item for item in to_filter if item not in as_float]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to use `set` to get the result.

```
to_filter=['age','height','name', 'address']
as_float=['age', 'height', 'weight']
are_float = set(to_filter)-set(as_float)
```